# Why is it that $f^{(n)}(a) \ne f_n(a)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

If

$$
f_n(z) = {f_{n-1}(z) - f_{n-1}(a) \over z - a}
$$

s.t. $f_n(a) = f'_{n-1}(a)$, why does this not imply that

$$
f^{(n)}(a) = f_n(a)\text{?}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the functions $f_1$ and $f'$ have the same value at $a$, but they are otherwise different (in general).

Take for example $f(z)=z^2$, $a=1$.
Then
$$f_1(z)=\frac{z^2-1}{z-1}=z+1$$
$$f_2(z)=\frac{z-1}{z-1}=1$$

but $f''(1)=2$.

Comment: This is a very simple and eloquent counter-example to my original understanding of the $f_n$ for $n \ge 2$.  I'm now not as sure what these $f_n$ are trying to intuitively capture.

Answer (score 0):

your question is unclear as you have not defined what $ f(x)$ is.

however it can be easily proven that $ (n-1)f^{(n)}_{n}(a) = f^{(n)}_{n-1}(a)$

this can be done by multiplying both sides of the given equation by $(z-a)$ and differentiating n times.

similarly, replacing n by n-k in the first equation, we get $ (n-1)f^{(n)}_{n-k}(a) = f^{(n)}_{n-k-1}(a)$

thus $ (n-1)^kf^{(n)}_{n}(a) = f^{(n)}_{n-k}(a)$

when $k=n$, we get, $ (n-1)^{(n-1)}f^{(n)}_{n}(a) = f^{(n)}_{1}(a)$